# FreeBSD mount_nullfs / nullfs results in Operation not permitted

Tags: mount, freebsd

I'm using FreeBSD as a local web server and I want to use SFTP to access the project files. I created a user, but I don't want the user to be able to navigate above their home directory.

User shell: `/usr/sbin/nologin`

User home: `/usr/home/username`

I am able to establish an SFTP connection as the user, but I need to make project files accessible for manipulation.

Project files are in `/usr/local/www/nginx/projectname`

Based on an answer from a related question, I tried:

`mount_nullfs /usr/local/www/nginx/projectname /usr/home/username`

but that only results in "**Operation not permitted**".

I have been searching for a while now and cannot determine why this is not working. How can I accomplish this?

Edit:

- Tried mounting as root
- I'm able to chroot home the user to the project directory
- Should mention this server is a jail in freenas, but both directories are in the same server.

Answer (score 0):

At first I will assume that you in `sshd_config` have something along the lines of:

```
Port 22

PermitRootLogin no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no

Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Second I assume that you are doing the nullfs mount as a regular user. Regular users are normally not allowed to mount file systems. If I try as root - it works for me.

Test it as root (either `sudo` or `su`) to confirm you have the paths correct. Then add it to `/etc/fstab`

```
/usr/local/www/nginx/projectname       /usr/home/username     nullfs    rw     0      0
```

That should be enough.

In this case it does not make sense to allow a regular user to mount anything. But that can be done by setting `vfs.usermount=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and adding `devfs` rules if `/dev/` is needed.

Finally - if you are using `ChrootDirectory` you could simply set the users home directly as `/usr/local/www/nginx/projectname`. The indirection using nullfs might give an extra layer of security. But if you trust your `sshd_config` then that is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've added more info. Still cannot get nullfs beyond the operation not permitted. `root@server:~ # mount_nullfs /usr/local/www/nginx/projectname /home/username/project
mount_nullfs: /usr/home/username/project: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Make sure you are not mounting links. And try /use/home

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify the jail configuration to allow mounting nullfs inside a jail. That is not normally something that is allowed inside a jail for security reasons. I would recommend against it.

You could configure the nullfs mount on the host system (in /etc/fstab), but this is more difficult with FreeNAS because of the way it stores its configuration.

Comment: So, what configuration exactly should be performed to allow nullfs mounts inside a jail?

Comment: You'd need to have: allow.mount.nullfs in your jail.conf

Comment: Apart from `allow.mount.nullfs` I had to set another parameter: `jail -m jid=X enforce_statfs=1`.